# Did i write this correctly? I keep on getting compiler errors

Tags: java

I'm not sure if I'm writing this correctly. I've checked my notes to make sure all appropriate symbols are used but I keep on getting errors like: ';' expected and not a statement. Did I miss something???

import java.util.Scanner;

public class EmployeeAbsences {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

employees = showEmployees();
totaldays = getDays(employees);
average = averageDays(employees, totaldays);

System.out.print("Your employees averaged " + average + " days absent.");


int showEmployees();

{
    int employees;

    System.out.print("How many employees do you have?");
    employees = keyboard.next.Int();

    while (employees > 0)
    {
        if (employees < 0) {
            System.out.print("Please enter a positive number.");
        }
        else
            {
                return employees;
            }
    }


}

int getDays(int employees);

{
    int totaldays = 0;
    int days;

    for (int x = 0; x <= days; x++)
    {
        System.out.print("How many days was Employee #" + x + " absent?");
        days = keyboard.next.Int();
        totaldays = days;
        totaldays = totaldays += days;
    }

    while (days > 0)
    {
        if (days < 0) { 
            System.out.print("Please enter a positive number."); 
        }
        else 
            {
                return totaldays;
            }
    }

}

double averageDays(employees, totaldays) 

{
    int totaldays;
    int employees;
    double average;

    average = totaldays/employees;
    {
        return average;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: here is error `int showEmployees();` remove `;`

Comment: Please do not update your question in such a way that it invalidates the answers. Also double check so that the code is properly formatted.

Answer (score 5):

Your methods (for example `showEmployees`) shouldn't be inside the main method and they shouldn't have semi-colon after their declaration :

Change

```
int showEmployees();
{
   ...
}
```

to

```
int showEmployees()
{
   ...
}
```

and move it outside the main method.

The same applies to `getDays` and `averageDays`.

It also appears that your methods are lacking some return statements. Each execution path must have a return statement. For example, `getDays` has a return statement only inside the while loop. There must be at least one more return statement after the while loop, in case the while loop is never entered.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the semicolon from  `int averageDays(employees, totaldays);` etc.

Answer (score 1):

for every method you write you should omit `;` , e.g:

```
 int showEmployees()
    {
        int employees;

        System.out.print("How many employees do you have?");
        employees = keyboard.next.Int();

        while (employees > 0)
        {
            if (employees < 0) {
                System.out.print("Please enter a positive number.");
            }
            else
                {
                    return employees;
                }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Drop the semicolon from all method declarations
2. Declare the type of `employees`, `totaldays` and `average` at the begining
3. Most of the functions have the return value inside de `while`, you should return something, also if it dont get into the `while` statement.
4. `averageDays` function is returning a `double` but it in its declaration it says it returns an `int`
5. in `getDays` function you need to initialize the `days` variable